# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename invoking shutil.copy()

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm working on a program in Python that copies all the mp3 files in a folder to another destination, but I'm facing a problem.

This is the code:

```
import os
import shutil
def copy_music():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\hp\Downloads")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("current working directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\hp\Downloads")
    for file_name in file_list:
        test = file_name.endswith('.mp3')
        if test == True:
            shutil.copy(file_name, 'c:\Users\hp\music')
    os.chdir(saved_path)
    print('all the mp3 files are successfully copied to your destination')
copy_music()
```

This is the error message:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/projects/code/copymusic.py", line 14, in <module>
    copy_music()
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/projects/code/copymusic.py", line 11, in copy_music
    shutil.copy(file_name, 'c:\Users\hp\music')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 133, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'Arcangel ?Bad Bunny - Original [Official Video].mp3'
```

Comment: Possible help: "Filenames on windows cannot contain ? characters" - From https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3210

Comment: Can you show us the hexadecimals of the characters in `file_name` by adding the following line before passing `file_name` to `shutil.copy`? `print(" ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in file_name))`